Column width in row range that sums to a referenced value
Cell A2 contains my current inventory of an SKU in units. IN C2:BB2, I have a forecast of the weekly demand in units for that SKU that will be taken from my inventory.



Inventory Qty
WOS
wk1
wk2
wk3
wk4
etc...




40000

10000
10000
10000
10000




In cell B2, under WOS (weeks of supply), I would like a formula that will calculate how many weeks my current inventory can cover, i.e., the width of the range in C2:BB2 for which the sum of values is less than or equal to the value in A2.
I have tried explaining this ask to a GPT several times, but it continues to spew made-up functions and formulas that do not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Where are you getting this SCAN function? I don't have it.

I feel a UDF would be appropriate to display the week number through the nth week.

@MayukhBhattacharya , In attempting to use the above listed function, I continually get "53" as the answer.  What output are you receiving?  I did a mock-up of data through week 6, losing 10k units per week of the 40k units (zero units available at four weeks).

@Cyril you are right, it is not correct. I found out what you said. I will delete it.

Going back a few years, you used to have to use Mmult if you wanted to do it one go (Offset also possible, but deprecated).
=MATCH(A2,MMULT(C2:G2,N(TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C2:G2))<=COLUMN(C2:G2))))


This will produce an error if inventory can't cover the first week, so
=IFERROR(MATCH(A2,MMULT(C2:G2,N(TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C2:G2))<=COLUMN(C2:G2)))),0)


=COUNT(LET(z,SCAN(A2,C2:L2,LAMBDA(a,b,a-b)),FILTER(z,z>=0)))



Excel 365 solution. This seems to be working but it's very clunky, no doubt Mayukh and the gang will be able to streamline it and make it more compact. If you don't have Excel 365, you will likely needs VBA or you can do it with helper rows.
=LET(
projection,C14:G14,
inventory,A14,
cumulative, SCAN(0, projection, LAMBDA(a,b, a + b)),
last_full_week,XMATCH(inventory,cumulative,-1),
first_partial_week,XMATCH(inventory,cumulative,1),
IFNA(IF(last_full_week=first_partial_week,last_full_week,
last_full_week+(INDEX(projection,,first_partial_week)-INDEX(projection,,last_full_week))/7),"Full"))


